# Naming join table

Tags: sql, database, coding-style

I am following this style: Tables are named in singular nouns. How would you name a join table then? Would you keep the naming such as `question_test` if it was two tables `test` and `question`?

And would you add something like `_join` so that you won't use the `question_test` if you need it later for a "normal" table? So `question_test_join`?

And the last question is if it is a convention to keep the names in join tables sorted alphabetically?

Comment: Probably would be better on the code review stack exchange since this isn't a specific programming issue.

Comment: This is really a subjective issue with no "right" answer.

Comment: Why can't someone just give a decent answer when the question is legit instead of closing down everything?

Comment: The question is not voted for closing because it is not legit but because people think you'll get better answers over in codereview.

Comment: @Dude: because this site is dominated by website developers who have great difficulty grasping that the world of programming is vastly larger than their own narrow expertise.  And because SO has a policy of not asking anyone to account for Closing questions.

Comment: Oh, and for those Voting to Close: this question does ***not*** meet the requirements to be on-topic for the codereview site.  But it ***does*** meet the requirements to be on-topic for SO.

Answer (score 2):

I would name the relationship table as `question_test` and don't expect some other table with the same name to exist but has no relation with either `test` table or `question` table that happen to the domain objects in the application. In similar situations in our application about request tracking system, we named the relationship tables this way.